# Angular is not showing all data in form when I perform more of one API endpoint call

Tags: angular

I have a component with a formulary. When I'm editing an existing element, all data is loaded in the formulary. A list of platforms and a list of categories is gathered also from the API. The lists are used to populate two selects. All data is injected in the form using a FormBuilder instance. If I gather only the data for the element to edit, without gather any list, all fields are populated correctly. When I gather one of the lists, the first element of the form is not populated. If I gather two lists from API, there are two fields in form that won't be populated. But if I look in the variable that contains data, all fields has data and aren't null. I tried to chain API calls but this don't work, I get the same behaviour.

This is my TS code:

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ApplicationsService} from '../../../Services/applications.service';
import {ApplicationModel} from '../../../Models/ApplicationModel';
import {LicenseModel} from '../../../Models/LicenseModel';
import {LicenseService} from '../../../Services/license.service';
import {PlatformsModel} from '../../../Models/PlatformsModel';
import {PlatformsService} from '../../../Services/platforms.service';
import {concat} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-app',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-app.component.html'
})
export class AddEditAppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private applicationsService: ApplicationsService,
              private licensesService: LicenseService,
              private platformsService: PlatformsService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  addEditForm: FormGroup;
  mode = 'add';
  id: number;
  application: ApplicationModel;
  licenses: LicenseModel[];
  platforms: PlatformsModel[];

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.licensesService.getAllLicenses().subscribe(lics => {
      this.licenses = lics;
      this.platformsService.getAllPlatforms().subscribe(plats => {
        this.platforms = plats;
        this.loadApplication();
      });
    });
  }

  loadApplication() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    if (id !== null) {
      this.id = Number.parseInt(id, 10);
      this.mode = 'edit';
      this.applicationsService.getApplicationById(this.id).subscribe(plat => {
        this.application = plat;
        this.createFormGroup();
      });
    } else {
      this.application = new ApplicationModel();
      this.mode = 'add';
      this.createFormGroup();
    }
  }

  createFormGroup() {

    const platIds: number[] = [];
    this.application.platforms.forEach(plat => {
      platIds.push(plat.id);
    });

    this.addEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [this.application.name],
      shortDescription: [this.application.shortDescription],
      longDescription: [this.application.longDescription],
      license: [this.application.license.id],
      isOpenSource: [this.application.isOpenSource],
      platforms: [platIds],
      officialWebsite: [this.application.officialWebsite],
      tags: [this.application.tags],
      categories: [this.application.categories],
      appIcon: [this.application.appIcon],
      captures: [this.application.captures],
      videos: [this.application.videos],
      twitter: [this.application.twitter],
      facebook: [this.application.facebook],
      author: [this.application.author],
      authorWebsite: [this.application.authorWebsite],
      codeUrl: [this.application.codeUrl],
      macAppStore: [this.application.macAppStore],
      windowsStore: [this.application.windowsStore],
      ubuntuSoftCenter: [this.application.ubuntuSoftCenter],
      macVersions: [this.application.macVersions],
      windowsVersions: [this.application.windowsVersions],
      linuxVersions: [this.application.linuxVersions],
      isActive: [this.application.isActive]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.addEditForm.valid) {

      const sendData = this.addEditForm.value;

      // Llicència
      sendData.license = this.licenses.find(l => l.id === Number.parseInt(sendData.license, 10));

      // Plataformes
      const plats = sendData.platforms;
      const sendPlats: PlatformsModel[] = [];
      plats.forEach(p => {
        sendPlats.push(this.platforms.find(plt => plt.id === Number.parseInt(p, 10)));
      });
      sendData.platforms = sendPlats;

      if (this.mode === 'add') {
        this.applicationsService.addApplication(sendData)
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.router.navigate(['/apps']);
          });
      } else {
        if (this.id !== null) {
          this.applicationsService.updateApplication(this.id, sendData)
            .subscribe(data => {
              this.router.navigate(['/apps']);
            });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved my problem, that is due to a bad initialisation practices. When I load the form with only one API endpoint call, all works good, all data is loaded and all uninitialised variables are initialized properly, but when I want lo load from more of one endpoint these uninitialised variables are throwing errors. So what I did:

- Call for the first time the form constructor before any API call, so, in this case the form is initialised.
- Initialise all class attributes
- Load all data from API
- Recall the form constructor in order to load the gathered data.